# HADOOPFS - Could not verify the base directory in streamsets

Tags: streamsets

I am having issues running the Pipeline with in streamsets, I can see the following error is :

```
HADOOPFS_44 - Could not verify the base directory: 'java.net.ConnectException: Call From SDC/...... to ......failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

**For more details see:**
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/ConnectionRefused

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the link

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the [steps given in the Hadoop wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/ConnectionRefused). The machine running StreamSets Data Collector cannot connect to the Hadoop cluster for some reason.